# rasa init saying command not found on windows

Tags: rasa

I'm on Windows, using Python 3.9 and installed rasa in my venv. It says installation succeeded, but when I run `rasa init` it says command not found.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rasa doesn't support Python 3.9 yet. Can you please try creating a venv with 3.6, 3.7, or 3.8?
Also, I'm not very familiar with windows but you may need to start a new terminal session for the `rasa` command to be visible in your path.

Answer (score 0):

When a program is successfully installed in Windows, it means that it is copied to where you wanted it to be installed. When you open a command shell (say using "cmd" in dialog opened using Windows button + "R" simultanesouly), it still has to know about installed programs which can be anywhere on the connected disks.

Type "set" in the cmd shell to see the list of all variables. To define the env variable FOO to the value bar, type "set FOO=bar".
To update the value of FOO variable to its previous value + bar, type "set FOO=%FOO%bar". Now FOO has the value barbar.

Now, you know how to update the PATH environment variable to its previous value plus the new path, with a semi colon.

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\MY\NEW\PATH

Your new program should be in this folder. Have fun!